# User.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') getting this error in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
 

export class User extends Component {
  
componentDidMount(){
  
  console.log(this.props);
   this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.login);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>User</div>
    )
  }
}

export default User


am getting below error

Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at User.componentDidMount (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:770:41)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33125:34)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34292:13)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34281:11)
    at commitLayoutEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34227:7)
    at commitRootImpl (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36137:9)
    at commitRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36017:9)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35526:7)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23529:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35130:17
```

am getting above error while trying to access the query string params login.
am new to react js , any suggestion do you have?